# Concatenate sparse matrices in Python using SciPy/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

What would be the most efficient way to concatenate sparse matrices in Python using SciPy/Numpy?

Here I used the following:

```
>>> np.hstack((X, X2))
array([ <49998x70000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 1135520 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
        <49998x70000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 1135520 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], 
       dtype=object)
```

I would like to use both predictors in a regression, but the current format is obviously not what I'm looking for. Would it be possible to get the following:

```
    <49998x1400000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
     with 2271040 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

It is too large to be converted to a deep format.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use the `scipy.sparse.hstack` to concatenate sparse matrices with the same number of rows (horizontal concatenation):

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack
hstack((X, X2))
```

Similarly, you can use `scipy.sparse.vstack` to concatenate sparse matrices with the same number of columns (vertical concatenation).

Using `numpy.hstack` or `numpy.vstack` will create an array with two sparse matrix objects.

Comment: Seems hstack is quite slow, check this post out on a similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33259578/6485667)

Comment: @simeon interesting that Scipy's dev team hasn't adopted such efficient solution

Comment: For the horizontal concatenation hstack() and for the vertical concatenation vstack() can be used.