# value error with array dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

I compute an array and it has a shape = 800*1140. The ndarray was generated from a previous step and the elements were stacked using hstack. I need to insert this into the scikitlearn for training and I have the following error:

**ValueError: Found array with dim 1140. Expected 800**

I think my error might be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314088/merging-to-numpy-arrays-with-different-column-dimensions) but I do not know how to proceed.

Can someone give me pointers ? Here is the code that causes the error : error is caused while running line XTrain.....

```
X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(self.featureMatrix)
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
X_scaled = imp.fit_transform(X_scaled)
classiFier = svm.SVC(C=10, cache_size=1500, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
XTrain, XTest, yTrain, yTest = cv.train_test_split(X_scaled,
                                                       self.classID,
                                                       test_size=0.4,
                                                       random_state=0)
```

Here is the entire Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2358, in <module>
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1778, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition#
4.5.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
File "C:/Users/vaidvj/svn/idmt/core/wrappers/afp/test/data/Urban_Sound_DB
/train&testSVM_MF.py", line 133, in <module>
c.process()
File "C:/Users/vaidvj/svn/idmt/core/wrappers/afp/test/data/Urban_Sound_DB
/train&testSVM_MF.py", line 129, in process
self.confMatcal( self.MfeatureMatrix, self.classID, self.uniqueClassLabels)
File "C:/Users/vaidvj/svn/idmt/core/wrappers/afp/test/data/Urban_Sound_DB/train&testSVM_MF.py", line 49, in confMatcal
random_state=0)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1556, in train_test_split
arrays = check_arrays(*arrays, **options)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 254, in check_arrays
% (size, n_samples))
ValueError: Found array with dim 1140. Expected 800
```

thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code that generates the error, difficult for people to reverse engineer code from errors

Comment: I will edit the main post.

Comment: Can you post Xscaled and classID respective shapes ? (using Xscaled.shape, etc)

Comment: 1. I did transpose the X_scaled. 
2. The shape of the array before I scaled was 800*1140 and now I see that scaling caused it change shape into 800*1127. The classID is of length 1140.

Comment: First of all, shapes are not `xx*yy` but `(xx, yy)`. Then I do not see  how 1140 got changed to 1127. X_scaled should be of shape `(1140, 800)`, which you can obtain by transposing your original X_scaled as I suggested: `X_scaled = np.transpose(X_scaled)`

Comment: @M.Massias: I added some more code to give you some info.
Yes, I know that shapes are (xx,yy). It was a typo, I am sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how you went from 1140 observations to 1127.

Comment: after Imputation, it changes - I do not know why !

Comment: But this is not related to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just transpose your data, using `numpy.transpose()` or `yourArray.T`. scikit expects an array of shape `(n_samples, n_features)`, where `n_samples` is your number of observations and `n_features` is the dimension of the space they live in.

See [the doc of np.transpose()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) for examples.

Comment: using the transpose will throw an error :

ValueError: Found array with dim 800. Expected 1140

Comment: @VyasrajVaidya just try and feed `train_test_split()` two arrays, the first one of shape (1140, 800), the second of shape (1140, )`