# Python: Concatenating scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to Concatenate 2 sparse matrix by the help of hstack function. xtrain_cat is the output of DictVectorizer(encodes categorical values) and xtrain_num is a pandas cvs file.

```
    xtrain_num = sparse.csr_matrix(xtrain_num)
    print type(xtrain_num)
    print xtrain_cat.shape
    print xtrain_num.shape
    x_train_data = hstack(xtrain_cat,xtrain_num)
```

Error :

```
(1000, 2778)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
(1000, 2778)
(1000, 968)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Zohair\Bosch\Bosch.py", line 360, in <module>
    x_train_data = hstack(xtrain_cat,xtrain_num)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 464, in hstack
    return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 547, in bmat
    raise ValueError('blocks must be 2-D')
ValueError: blocks must be 2-D
```

Can someone identify what is the probelm

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710602/concatenate-sparse-matrices-in-python-using-scipy-numpy?rq=1

Comment: You should specify which `hstack` you used, `np.hstack` or `sparse.hstack`.  As the answer shows, this error is produced by the sparse version, run without the proper list of inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try:

```
x_train_data = hstack((xtrain_cat,xtrain_num))
```

[It takes a sequence](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html):

> **blocks** sequence of sparse matrices with compatible shapes

---

When I define `a` to be a sparse matrix, I can verify your error when I omit it (and correct it when I add it):

```
In [19]: sparse.hstack(a, a)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent     call last)
<ipython-input-19-7c450ab4fda0> in <module>()
----> 1 sparse.hstack(a, a)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.pyc in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    454 
    455     """
--> 456     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    457 
    458 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.pyc in     bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    537 
    538     if blocks.ndim != 2:
--> 539         raise ValueError('blocks must be 2-D')
    540 
    541     M,N = blocks.shape

ValueError: blocks must be 2-D

In [20]: sparse.hstack((a, a))
Out[20]: 
<3x8 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Comment: Right, `sparse.hstack` is trying to treat the first argument as a list of matrices, or `blocks`.  The `np.hstack` complains about the number of positional arguments.