# Sparse Matrix Concat

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sparse-matrix

Have a sparse matrix of shape (10,64) and have a numpy array with shape (10,). I want to concat the the matrices so the new matrix has dimensions (10,65).
I have tried this but I keep on getting this error 'ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated'

```
d = np.concatenate((a,np.concatenate(b)[:,None]),axis=1)
```

EDIT:

Working Solution

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np

C=np.vstack((A.A.T,B)).T
D=csr_matrix((C)) #
```

Comment: `np.column_stack((a,b)).shape` gives me `(10, 65)` on random arrays, if not you should include an example to show why or may be check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498299/how-to-column-stack-a-numpy-array-with-a-scipy-sparse-matrix)

Comment: @anky. I got this error when i used column_stack.  ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 10

Comment: yeah i missed sparse matrix , edited my comment, does the link help..?

Comment: Yep that worked, Thanks

Comment: If you want the result to be a sparse matrix, I'd suggest using one of the `sparse` 'stack' functions.  Those get the `coo` attributes of the input arrays, combine them, and make new `coo`  matrix from that.   `np.concatenate` tries to turn all its inputs into `numpy` arrays, but `np.asarray(sparse_M)` is the wrong way to do that.