# Stacking two sparse matrices with different dimensions

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I have two sparse-matrices (created out of `sklearn` `HashVectorizer`, from two sets of features - each set corresponds to a feature). I want to concatenate them to later use them for clustering. But, I am facing a problem with dimensions, as the two matrices do not have the same row dimensions.

Here is an example:

```
Xa = [-0.57735027 -0.57735027  0.57735027 -0.57735027 -0.57735027  0.57735027
  0.5         0.5        -0.5         0.5         0.5        -0.5         0.5
  0.5        -0.5         0.5        -0.5         0.5         0.5        -0.5
  0.5         0.5       ]

Xb = [-0.57735027 -0.57735027  0.57735027 -0.57735027  0.57735027  0.57735027
 -0.5         0.5         0.5         0.5        -0.5        -0.5         0.5
 -0.5        -0.5        -0.5         0.5         0.5       ]
```

Both `Xa` and `Xb` are of type `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>`. Shapes are `Xa.shape = (6, 1048576) Xb.shape = (5, 1048576)`. The error I get is (which I know now why it happens):

```
    X = hstack((Xa, Xb))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py", line 464, in hstack
    return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py", line 581, in bmat
    'row dimensions' % i)
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions
```

Is there a way to stack the sparse-matrices despite their irregular dimensions? Maybe with some padding?

I have looked into these posts:

- [Concatenate sparse matrices in Python using SciPy/Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710602/concatenate-sparse-matrices-in-python-using-scipy-numpy)
- [Is there an efficient way of concatenating scipy.sparse matrices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844998/is-there-an-efficient-way-of-concatenating-scipy-sparse-matrices).

Comment: can you post the shape of your matrices Xa and Xb?

Comment: updated post with shapes.

Comment: I think I found a work-around: concatenated using bumpy and converted the result to csr_matrix. Studying more to see if this is OK. Xc = np.concatenate([Xa.data, Xb.data])  and then doing: sm = sparse.csr_matrix(Xc).

Comment: Performance wise that is not a great idea, you should try to always keep the matrices in sparse format so you don't run out of memory. Did you try my answer?

Comment: Not yet tried. I am trying to understand what is happening. Please correct me if I am wrong: You are taking the matrix that has lower number of rows, vertical-stacking with a custom-matrix that has the difference of the row-numbers (here, 4-3 = 1) and the column-value being the same (Xb.shape[1]). Once you vstack it, the resulting matrix will have the same dimension as the other one. My question is this:  This custom-matrix you are vstacking - what are its contents? are they zeroes?

Comment: Yes I'm stacking with an empty sparse matrix, which by definition is all zeros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pad it with an empty sparse matrix.

You want to **horizontaly stack** it so you need to pad the smaller matrix so that it has the **same number of rows** as the larger matrix. For that you **vertically stack** it with a matrix of shape `(difference in number of rows, number of columns of original matrix)`.

Like this:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse import hstack
from scipy.sparse import vstack

# Create 2 empty sparse matrix for demo
Xa = csr_matrix((4, 4))
Xb = csr_matrix((3, 5))


diff_n_rows = Xa.shape[0] - Xb.shape[0]

Xb_new = vstack((Xb, csr_matrix((diff_n_rows, Xb.shape[1])))) 
#where diff_n_rows is the difference of the number of rows between Xa and Xb

X = hstack((Xa, Xb_new))
X
```

Which results in:

```
<4x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```